# Is P XOR (IF P THEN L) equal to NOT (P AND L)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would like to reduce this statement:$$ P \veebar (P \implies B) $$ using only $\neg$, $\land$ I've found this solution but I don't know if I'm wrong:
$$\neg(P \land B)$$
Because  the book proposes this one using XOR:
$$\neg P \veebar (P \land \neg B)$$
Is there any errors or things by which I should do the same?

---

Exercise 1.8-4 p.16 from *Analisi matematica vol.1* by *Enrico Giusti*

Comment: What your book suggests is only a hint, not a solution. The one you have arrived at is correct, see [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p+xor+%28p+implies+q%29%2C+%28not+p%29+xor+%28p+and+%28not+q%29%29%2C+not+%28p+and+q%29).

Comment: @dtldarek thanks for the link! in fact is with all the others solutions at the end of the chapters, maybe the author miss this solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. To check, let's unpack the initial formula:

$$P \oplus (P \rightarrow B)$$

$$P \oplus (\lnot P \lor B)$$

$$(P \lor (\lnot P \lor B))\land \lnot(P \land (\lnot P \lor B))$$

$$(\top \lor B)\land \lnot(P \land (\lnot P \lor B))$$

$$\top\land \lnot(P \land (\lnot P \lor B))$$

$$\lnot(P \land (\lnot P \lor B))$$

$$(\lnot P \lor \lnot(\lnot P \lor B))$$

$$(\lnot P \lor (P \land \lnot B))$$

$$(\lnot P \lor P) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot B)$$

$$\top \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot B)$$

$$(\lnot P \lor \lnot B)$$

Which, once De Morganed, is equivalent to your solution:

$$\lnot(P \land B)$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing out the truth tables for both we obtain the following:

```
P   B  (P⟹B)  [P⊻(P⟹B)]  ¬(P∧B)
0   0     1       1         1
0   1     1       1         1
1   0     0       1         1
1   1     1       0         0
```

Since all rows match here, it follows that your solution is correct.